# is this "although + present participle" structure possible?

Tags: conjunctions

I've encountered some "Although + present participle" structures. (1,2)
However, I feel a little bit weird sentence 3.
Could you explain why sentence 3 is not correct with some examples and references.

1. Although throwing the ball as high as he always does, he doesn’t get much admiration from the girls.
2. Although having made a fatal mistake, he went on typing the report.
3. Although it being a latecomer, the company has grown remarkably since its foundation, and finally has become the most profitable oil refiner in the country.
4. Despite it being a latecomer, the company has grown remarkably since its foundation, and finally has become the most profitable oil refiner in the country.

Comment: _Despite_ + present participle is correct, but I would always use an ordinary verb after _although_ - _Although he throws - Although he had - Although it is_.

Comment: "Although" can take a participial clause as complement, so 3. is fine

Comment: @BillJ - (3) isn't fine to me.

Comment: @KateBunting strangely #3 seems correct to me.

Comment: I don't think any of these sentences are correct.

Comment: See [this](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/in-spite-of-despite-although-even-though-and-though).

Comment: The British Council is hardly an authoritative resource on English grammar. Notice that it doesn't even mention the possibility of participial clauses as complement of "though" and "although".